# swift viewController inherit subclass UITableviewController(customiz)

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

i create base class  type of UITableViewController and i want to make in my app
from this base class other tableView's in other viewController's here is my code

**base class:**

```
class BaseTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {
private var _testArray:[String]!
private var _identifier:String!
init(array:[String],identifier:String) {
    _testArray = array
    _identifier = identifier
    super.init(style: .plain)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
public private (set) var array:[String] {
    get {
        return _testArray
    }
    set {
        return  _testArray = newValue
    }
}
public private (set) var identifier:String {
    get {
        return _identifier
    }
    set {
        return  _identifier = newValue
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self._testArray)

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return _testArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = _testArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

the code of the class that inherit the base class:

**inherit class:**

```
class ViewController:DemonTableTableViewController {
 @IBOutlet var tabelDemo: UITableView!
let arrayTest:[String] = ["cat","fish","dog"]
var identifierCell = "test"
var newTable:BaseTableTableViewController {
    return DemonTableTableViewController.init(array: arrayTest, identifier: identifierCell)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

i have 2 ERRORS:
1.unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(testArray)

2.when i fix this problem i get black screen and yes i did that initail view controller

Comment: 1. Test Array is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so you have to guarantee it has a value before its used (ie you have to assign it to something, even an empty array when you call init). 2. Initializing a viewController doesn't put it on screen. you need to add its view as a subview of some other view, embed it in another contoller (UINAvigationController, or UITabBarController, UISplitViewController, etc), or you make it the root view controller of your window in your AppDelegate.

Comment: replace var newTable:DemonTableTableViewController with var newTable: BaseTableTableViewController